# Making stack from many images in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis, ndvi, raster-dataset, rasterstack

Using the code below, I've computed 20 ndvi images for modis data.

How can I stack and save them in a single file?

```
var mod13 = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD13Q1")
.filterBounds(geometry)
.filterDate("2000-01-01","2001-01-01")
.select("NDVI");

var mod13ndvi = mod13.map( function(img){
  return img.multiply(0.0001)
  .copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);
});

print(mod13ndvi);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need the function 'toBands()' and apply that on the image collection. Unfortunately, the function cannot deal with similar band names (at least, for your MODIS collection: it works fine for landsat and Sentinel), so you will need to change the band names. For simplicity, I changed the band names to the date the image was acquired.

**Update:** bandnames are now renamed to only their date, eliminating the 'null_' the function toBands() appends to it when image number lacks.

```js
// Define a random geometry
var geometry = /* color: #0b4a8b */ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[-111.6384952013949, 33.80963070262341],
      [-111.7153994982699, 32.92883163730542],
      [-109.0017764513949, 33.526181694205995]]]);

// make the image collection
var mod13 = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD13Q1") .filterBounds(geometry) 
.filterDate("2000-01-01","2001-01-01") .select("NDVI");
print(mod13);

// change the name of the NDVI band to the image ID (date it is acquired)
var mod13ndvi = mod13.map( function(img){ 
  var id  = img.id()
  img = img.select('NDVI').rename(id);
return img.multiply(0.0001).copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']); });
print(mod13ndvi);

// Apply the function toBands() on the image collection to set all bands into one image
var multiband = mod13ndvi.toBands();
print(multiband)

// Reset the bandnames
var names = multiband.bandNames();
// rename the bandnames 
var newNames = names.map(function(name){
  var ind = names.indexOf(name);
  return ee.String(names.get(ind)).slice(5);
});
var multiband = multiband.rename(newNames);
print(multiband);
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/48569dcfe14420f0ed8f6729e3ec7d15

Comment: If I want to save all bands with correspond date (as band name), what should I do? could you help me, please?

Comment: You could replace id to make it more convenient by:

var dateString = ee.Date(img.get('system:time_start')).format('yyyy-MM-dd');

But it returns the exactly the same answers as img.id();

Answer (score -1):

thanks for your response , I've rewrite code like this:

```
var mod13 = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD13Q1")
.filterBounds(geometry)
.filterDate("2000-01-01","2001-01-01")
.select("NDVI");

var mod13ndvi = mod13.map( function(img){
  return img.multiply(0.0001)
  .copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);
});

print(mod13ndvi);

var multiband = mod13ndvi.iterate(function(image, result) {
  return ee.Image(result).addBands(image);
});


Export.image.toDrive({
  image : multiband,
  description : "stack_test_ex",
  scale : 250,
  region : geometry
})
```

but it doesn't save multi band and show this error:

> Error: Image.addBands, argument 'dstImg': Invalid type. Expected: Image. Actual: ImageCollection.