# Median NDVI for each pixel per month, and then clip to polygons and reduce by regions

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, ndvi

I would like to take the median of NDVI per month for each pixel, then for each field, reduce those medians to mean by for each region.

[This question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/290892/google-earth-enginesst-by-month-per-year:) answers how to take medians per month. So, after I take the median of each pixel and I pass that to my other function to do spatial mosaic and clip, the output has nothing in it.

Here is my code. I try to take medians for each pixel per month
in the line that says `print ("line 98", imageC);`.
when I pass the result of `extract_satellite_IC(.)` to `mosaic_and_reduce_IC_mean(.)`
to mosaic and reduce by region, in line 160 (`print ("reduced from 160, reduction function", reduced);`) my data disappears.

I think I will be fine also with first mosaic and reduce by region, and then take median of the time series data over each month. So, I tried to use the function `median_by_month(.)` at line 161 instead. That does not works neither.
The answers in these other questions are slightly different from my question.
for example [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/301447/calculating-ndvi-per-region-month-year-with-google-earth-engine) is one of them.

```
var SF = ee.FeatureCollection(shapeFilem); // shapeFilem is a shapefile with several polygons in it located in PNW. They all are contained within the big_rectangle.
var outfile_name_prefix = 'L5_T1C2L2_rangeLand_';
var wstart_date = '2000-01-01'; // YYYY-MM-DD
var wend_date = '2001-01-01'; // YYYY-MM-DD
var start_year = 2000;
var end_year = 2001; //
var outfile_name = outfile_name_prefix + wstart_date + "_" + wend_date;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////
///////     Functions
///////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////
//////   Median of each pixel across a month.
////// 
function median_by_month(ICC){
  var months = ee.List.sequence(1, 12);
  var years = ee.List.sequence(start_year, end_year);
  var byMonthYear = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  years.map(function(y) {
    return months.map(function (m) {
      return ICC.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
                 .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
                 .median()
                 .set('month', m).set('year', y);
                    });
                           }).flatten());
  return byMonthYear;
}

var cloudMaskL578_C2L2 = function(image) { ///  Function to clear clouds in Landsat-7
  var qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL');
  var cloud = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3).and(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 9))
                .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 4)); 
  return image.updateMask(cloud.not());
};

/// add Date of image to an imageCollection
function add_system_start_time_image(image) {
  image = image.addBands(image.metadata('system:time_start').rename("system_start_time"));
  return image;
}

function add_system_start_time_collection(colss){
 var c = colss.map(add_system_start_time_image);
 return c;
}

/// NDVI - Landsat-5
function addNDVI_to_image(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['SR_B4', 'SR_B3']).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
}

function add_NDVI_collection(image_IC){
  var NDVI_IC = image_IC.map(addNDVI_to_image);
  return NDVI_IC;
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////
///
///         scale the bands
///
function scale_the_bands(image){
  var NIR = image.select('SR_B4').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  var red = image.select('SR_B3').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  var blue = image.select('SR_B1').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);

  return image.addBands(NIR, null, true)
              .addBands(red, null, true)
              .addBands(blue, null, true);
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////
///
///         Do the Job
///

function extract_satellite_IC(a_feature, start_date, end_date){
    var geom = a_feature.geometry(); // a_feature is a feature collection
    var newDict = {'original_polygon_1': geom};
    var imageC = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1_L2')
                .filterDate(start_date, end_date)
                .filterBounds(geom)
                .map(function(image){return image.clip(geom)})
                .sort('system:time_start', true);
    
    // toss out cloudy pixels
    imageC = imageC.map(cloudMaskL578_C2L2);
    
    // scale the bands
    imageC = imageC.map(scale_the_bands);
    
    // imageC = imageC.map(clean_clouds_from_one_image_landsat);
    imageC = add_NDVI_collection(imageC); // add NDVI as a band
  
    imageC = add_system_start_time_collection(imageC);
    // print ("line 98", imageC);
    imageC=median_by_month(imageC);
    // print ("100", imageC);
    imageC=imageC.map(function(im){return(im.addBands(im.metadata('month')))});
    imageC=imageC.map(function(im){return(im.addBands(im.metadata('year')))});
    // print ("103", imageC);
    // add original geometry to each image. We do not need to do this really:
    imageC = imageC.map(function(im){return(im.set(newDict))});
    
    // add original geometry and WSDA data as a feature to the collection
    imageC = imageC.set({ 'original_polygon': geom});
    // print ("109", imageC);
  return imageC;
}

function mosaic_and_reduce_IC_mean(an_IC,a_feature, start_date, end_date){
  an_IC = ee.ImageCollection(an_IC);
  print ("line 115", an_IC);
  var reduction_geometry = a_feature;
  var start_date_DateType = ee.Date(start_date);
  var end_date_DateType = ee.Date(end_date);
  //######**************************************
  // Difference in days between start and end_date

  var diff = end_date_DateType.difference(start_date_DateType, 'day');

  // Make a list of all dates
  var range = ee.List.sequence(0, diff.subtract(1)).map(function(day){
                                    return start_date_DateType.advance(day,'day')});

  // Funtion for iteraton over the range of dates
  function day_mosaics(date, newlist) {
    // Cast
    date = ee.Date(date);
    newlist = ee.List(newlist);

    // Filter an_IC between date and the next day
    var filtered = an_IC.filterDate(date, date.advance(1, 'day'));
    var image = ee.Image(filtered.mosaic()); // Make the mosaic

    // Add the mosaic to a list only if the an_IC has images
    return ee.List(ee.Algorithms.If(filtered.size(), newlist.add(image), newlist));
  }

  // Iterate over the range to make a new list, 
  // and then cast the list to an imagecollection
  var newcol = ee.ImageCollection(ee.List(range.iterate(day_mosaics, ee.List([]))));

  //######**************************************

  var reduced = newcol.map(function(image){
                    return image.reduceRegions({
                                              collection:reduction_geometry,
                                              reducer:ee.Reducer.mean(), 
                                              scale: 10
                                                });
                                          }
                        ).flatten();

  reduced = reduced.set({ 'original_polygon': reduction_geometry});
  reduced=ee.ImageCollection(reduced);
  // print ("lin 159", reduced);
  print ("reduced from 160, reduction function", reduced);
  // reduced=median_by_month(reduced);
  // reduced=reduced.map(function(im){return(im.addBands(im.metadata('month')))});
  // reduced=reduced.map(function(im){return(im.addBands(im.metadata('year')))});
  // print ("reduced from 164", reduced);
  return(reduced);
}

// remove geometry on each feature before printing or exporting

var myproperties=function(feature){
  feature=ee.Feature(feature).setGeometry(null);
  return feature;
};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////
///////     Body
///////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var xmin = -123.5;
var xmax = -111.3;
var xmed1 = (xmin + xmax) / 2.0;
var ymax = 49.0;
var ymin = 42.2;
var ymed1 = (ymin + ymax) / 2.0;


var box1 = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[xmin, ymed1], [xmin, ymax], [xmed1, ymax], [xmed1, ymed1], [xmin, ymed1]]);
var box2 = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[xmed1, ymed1], [xmed1, ymax], [xmax, ymax], [xmax, ymed1], [xmed1, ymed1]]);
var box3 = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[xmin, ymin], [xmin, ymed1], [xmed1, ymed1], [xmed1, ymin], [xmin, ymin]]);
var box4 = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[xmed1, ymin], [xmed1, ymed1], [xmax, ymed1], [xmax, ymin], [xmed1, ymin]]);
var big_rectangle = [box1, box2, box3, box4];

var SF_regions = ee.FeatureCollection(big_rectangle);
var reduction_geometry = ee.FeatureCollection(SF);

Map.addLayer(SF_regions, {color: 'red'}, 'WA');
Map.addLayer(SF, {color: 'blue'}, 'SF');
var ymed = (ymin + ymax)/2.0;
Map.setCenter(xmed1, ymed, 2);

var imageC = extract_satellite_IC(SF_regions, wstart_date, wend_date);
var reduced = mosaic_and_reduce_IC_mean(imageC, reduction_geometry, wstart_date, wend_date);  

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: reduced,
  description:outfile_name,
  folder: "savingFolder",
  fileNamePrefix: outfile_name,
  fileFormat: 'CSV',
  selectors:["long", 'lat', 'NDVI', "system_start_time"]
});
```