# GEE Add image properties to band name

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am extracting monthly CHIRPS precipitation data using an image stack, and want to add image dates to the band names. Before creating the stack, I created two new image properties, `'month'`and `'year'`. I want to concatenate these properties to the `'precipitation'` band of each image in the collection, such that each band has the following format: `'precipitation_YYYY_MM'`.

[Script here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/6a721ebaaa9f2dd4bdd87dd75e68ed4c)

Per the answer from the question [GEE - Add date to band names in ImageCollection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/354781/147679), I have a function that takes the `'month'`and `'year'` properties of the image, and tries to concatenate that with the existing bandname:

```js
var renamed = monthlycolmean.map(function(image) {
    var month = image.get('month');
    var year = image.get('year');
    return image.rename(image.bandNames().map(function(bandName){
      return ee.String(bandName).cat(month).cat(year);
    }));
  });
```

However, I get this error:

```js
ImageCollection (Error)
Error in map(ID=0):
Image.rename: Invalid band name: 'precipitation1.01981.0'.
```

I have also tried to use `image.getString()` instead of `image.get()` to pull the month and year properties as strings, but that fails with the following error:

```js
ImageCollection (Error)
Error in map(ID=0):
Element.getString: Unable to cast value to String.
```

How do I rename correctly so that bandnames are formatted like `'precipitation_YYYY_MM'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use "." in band names and without specifying any formatting, the numbers are getting printed at 1.0 and 1981.0.  Use "_" instead and force the formatting to be integer:

```
var month = image.getNumber('month').format("_%d")
var year = image.getNumber('year').format("_%d");
```

Comment: Ah, thanks Noel! The formatting tip fixed my issue.